# PostSharp intercept class constructor and destructor calls

Tags: postsharp

Is it possible to intercept class constructor and destructor calls using PostSharp? I would like to create active instances counter for classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OnMethodBoundaryAspect on constructor and destructors. Note that classes don't have destructors by default in C# and VB, and destructors are called at a non-deterministic moment.

Remember that constructors can be called in chain, and the aspect is going to be applied on every constructor in the chain.